# Are the files given permission with chmod +x saved somewhere?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, permission

I am currently following one python3 course at the time. For easy execution, they suggest running the following code:

```
chmod +x pythonFileName.py
```

Doing so, made it possible to run the file using: `./pythonFileName.py` and this is of course much easier then navigation the entire folder structure to find my scripts.

I am wondering, are these files copied to any hidden folder? How does this command even work? I mean how does he know the right path? If I delete the script do I need to run another code? Delete the copied file from a hidden folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`chmod +x /path/to/file` sets the execute permission on the file itself. It doesn't maintain a separate list of permissions for standard read/write/execute, just sets that to the file.

> Are these files copied to any hidden folder?

No, the file remains where it is. The permission is set to the file in place.

> How does this command even work?

POSIX file permissions include read/write/execute permissions. Running `+x` adds the execute permission to all, `-x` removes it.

> How does he know the right path?

You provide the path to the command when you run it. `/path/to/file` is the path you provided when you run the command.

> If I delete the script do I need to run another code?

You can delete the file as usual, with `rm` or using Finder, without needing to run anything else. If you create a new file (regardless of the name) you will need to `chmod +x /path/to/file` to give it the execute permission again.

> Delete the copied file from a hidden folder?

There's no copying taking place when you run chmod so there's nothing else to delete.